# Programmatically determine clipboard source information

Tags: windows, clipboard

When a user copies text to the clipboard, is it possible in Windows to programmatically identify the source file (and/or URL) and text position?

I have looked at a bunch of clipboard management applications (Ditto, clipboardFusion, ArsClip, and ClipDiary) and none appears to record the source of a clip.

It is my belief that this functionality in not possible, but I would like another opinion or two before I abandon my attempts.

I currently think the only way to achieve the desired behavior is to create an add-on / extension for every application that will be copied from. The extension would override the applications normal copy to clipboard behavior with a new format that adds the additional information. The key applications for me would be adobe acrobat (or another pdf reader) and a browser.

Comment: IMHO it's not possible, but I can't give you any references to support this - there just isn't that level of info in the clipboard API functions.

Comment: You might be able to write a Windows service that listens for the Clipboard copy event and records the text along with the active Window's details (the Window that likely fired the copy event). Best I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not require any source information to be given when [setting clipboard data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051(v=vs.85).aspx). Additionally, the only information needed to enable calling that function is a window handle. As such, the best windows could give you in a general case is the window handle that set the clipboard data via [GetClipboardOwner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649041(v=vs.85).aspx).

Some applications set some of the formats on the clipboard to the source location of other data on the clipboard, but again in a general sense, there need not even be any source data; an application can just place random arbitrary data on the clipboard.

For your specific use case, you may be able to write a grease-monkey script to add your meta-data, and as firefox/chrome can display PDFs you might even be able to use the same script for PDFs.